# CKeditor justify whole block to left/right/center

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, justify

I'm trying to override default justify left/right/center in creditor 4 so they will justify whole text to left/right/center instead of every line separately. I've added code below into creditor.config.js and all works ok but I can't update/refresh new values in ckeditor. Looks like setData() does update ckeditor values but it executes in a loop, tried wrapping it in setTimout() but that doesn't change anything. Tried update element, setValue, setHtml...

`CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
     ev.editor.on('selectionChange', function () {
        var text = ev.editor.getData();
        text = text.replace(new RegExp('(class="rtecenter")|(class="rteleft") |(class="rteright")','g'),'');
        text = '<div class="rteleft">'+text+'</div>';
        // ev.editor.setData(text);
        // ev.editor.element.setValue(text);
        // ev.editor.element.setHtml(text);
    });
});`

Comment: I've just started working with CKEditor myself, so I'm no expert, but are you sure you want to do this every time the selection changes? I would imagine this will break the editor making actually editing the text impossible, because the underlying HTML will change every time the user just clicks somewhere. (Besides there is so much other things wrong with your code.) You may want to write a plugin that does your modification on a button click. (Cont.)

Comment: Or maybe just defining a new style may be enough. What exactly do you mean with "justify whole text to left/right/center instead of every line separately"? Can you give an example how you want to modify the HTML?

Comment: First of all - don't change data if you want to do something "live". You need to work on DOM. Second - why don't you use stylesheet (in `contents.css`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, thanks! 
Got it working eventually, pretty simple... 
i.e. This is how to override 'justifycenter' command in CKEditor 4 :

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {

```
    var editor = ev.editor;
    var overridecmd_justifycenter = new CKEDITOR.command(editor, {
        exec: function(editor){
            var ps = editor.document.$.getElementsByTagName("p");
            for (var i=0; i < ps.length; i++){
                if(ps[i].className.indexOf("rtecenter") < 0) {
                    ps[i].className = "rtecenter";
                }
            } 
        }
    });

    // Replace default button commands with overrides
    ev.editor.commands.justifycenter.exec = overridecmd_justifycenter.exec;
```

});